# Browser back button not going back to old url with query params using react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am updating query params everytime some filter changes but clicking on browser back button going to a route without query params.

eg. I'm in hats page -> I selected a colour filter then I do `navigate('/hats?colour=abc')` and again select price filter then I do `navigate('/hats?colour=abc&price=500')`.

Now if I click on browser back button it goes directly to `/hats` instead of previous route `'/hats?colour=abc'`.

How can achieve this ?

Expected behaviour - On clicking browser back button it should go from `'/hats?colour=abc&price=500'` to `'/hats?colour=abc'`.

Comment: How are you adding the query params and navigating? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah I added and it worked. It was not supported in hookrouter which I used earlier. Thanks